# Kraken API DASHXXBT asset pair not working

Tags: node.js, kraken.com

I am consuming Kraken API and using the Depth request to get the order books. I understand the pairs (parameter for Depth) are the composition of base and quote that you can find in the assetpair call. In fact:
https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Depth?pair=XLTCXXBT
is working as expected.

But when I try DASH
https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Depth?pair=DASHXXBT 
I always get:

```
{"error":["EQuery:Unknown asset pair"]}
```

Nonetheless in the assetpair response you can find base: DASH quote: XXBT

https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs

```
...
{"altname":"DASHXBT","aclass_base":"currency",**"base":"DASH"**,
"aclass_quote":"currency",**"quote":"XXBT"**,"lot":"unit","pair_decimals":5,"lot_decimals":8,"lot_multiplier":1,"leverage_buy":[],"leverage_sell":[],"fees":[[0,0.26],[50000,0.24],[100000,0.22],[250000,0.2],[500000,0.18],[1000000,0.16],[2500000,0.14],[5000000,0.12],[10000000,0.1]],"fees_maker":[[0,0.16],[50000,0.14],[100000,0.12],[250000,0.1],[500000,0.08],[1000000,0.06],[2500000,0.04],[5000000,0.02],[10000000,0]],"fee_volume_currency":"ZUSD","margin_call":80,"margin_stop":40}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: its open data, kraken is a well known trading platform, is here "kraken" intended as something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so basically for DASH there is a special rule of some sort, the working AssetPair is only DASHXBT, DASHXXBT is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the available trading pair un Kraken on the AssetPairs endpoint

https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs

Here is the result

[image]

Here is the same in a PHP array. Double check this tab as it might not be up to date. Also I removed the .d because it have been deactivated.

```
private $KRAKEN_CODE_PAIR = array(
    'pair' =>

        // BCH
        "BCHEUR"  . ',' .
        "BCHUSD"  . ',' .
        "BCHXBT"  . ',' .

        // DASH
        'DASHEUR' . ',' .
        'DASHUSD' . ',' .
        'DASHXBT' . ',' .

        // EOS
        'EOSETH' . ',' .
        'EOSXBT' . ',' .

        // GNO
        "GNOETH"  . ',' .
        "GNOXBT"   . ',' .

        //USDT
        "USDTZUSD"   . ',' .

        //ETC
        "XETCXETH"   . ',' .
        "XETCXXBT"  . ',' .
        "XETCZEUR"  . ',' .
        "XETCZUSD"  . ',' .

        // ETH
        'XETHXXBT' . ',' .
        'XETHZEUR' . ',' .
        'XETHZUSD' . ',' .
        "XETHZCAD" . ',' .
        "XETHZGBP" . ',' .
        "XETHZJPY" . ',' .

        // ICONOMI
        'XICNXXBT' . ',' .
        'XICNXETH' . ',' .

        // LTC
        'XLTCXXBT' . ',' .
        'XLTCZEUR' . ',' .
        'XLTCZUSD' . ',' .

        // MLN
        "XMLNXETH" . ',' .
        "XMLNXXBT" . ',' .

        // AUGUR
        "XREPXETH" . ',' .
        "XREPXXBT". ',' .
        "XREPZEUR". ',' .

        //XBT
        "XXBTZCAD". ',' .
        "XXBTZEUR". ',' .
        "XXBTZGBP". ',' .
        "XXBTZJPY". ',' .
        "XXBTZUSD". ',' .

        // XDG
        "XXDGXXBT". ',' .

        // XLM
        "XXLMXXBT". ',' .

        // XMR
        "XXMRXXBT". ',' .
        "XXMRZEUR". ',' .
        "XXMRZUSD". ',' .

        // XRP
        "XXRPXXBT". ',' .
        "XXRPZEUR". ',' .
        "XXRPZUSD". ',' .

        // ZEC
        "XZECXXBT". ',' .
        "XZECZEUR". ',' .
        "XZECZUSD"
);
```